# Code Signing Certificates To VSTO Add-In For MS Excel by C#

Tags: c#, excel, ssl, vsto, code-signing

I have few doubts before adding Code Signing Certificate to my **VSTO Add-In** for MS Excel by C#.

1. How **Code Signing Certificate** will work for **VSTO Add-Ins**
2. Is there any need of manual step to add Code Signing certificate to client PC at the time of application setup
3. How to add code signing certificate to VSTO Add-In project
4. If I use setup project for my Add-In, to which project do I need to add Certificate (either **Setup Project** or **VSTO Add-In Project**)
5. Can I use one certificate for different multiple projects?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeamsgdev/2014/06/10/how-to-create-and-use-a-code-signing-certificate-for-clickonce-vsto-applications-using-active-directory-certificate-services/ should apply in reference to this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668205.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Check out this article I wrote in TechNet [How to create a non expiring certificate in Visual Studio.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40155.visual-studio-how-to-create-a-non-expiring-certificate.aspx)
2. It depends if the install is on a network or deployed to a website.
3. After you create your own certificate you can select the file in the project properties.
4. If you deploy the VSTO Addin using ClickOnce, it's the solution as the VSTO project.
5. Yes, the same certificate can be used in multiple projects

Comment: What format should the certificate have? I am trying to export a certificate for code signing from certmgr but I cannot have the .pfx format for some reason! Any other acceptable formats for signing?